# PositionalDataSource and recyclerview. Why scroll after invalidate()?

Tags: java

- Here my fragment
- Here is my DataSource
- For test every 10s I call invalidate() (for test). Datasource not changes. My recycleview scroll one page every 10s.

Why?

Log
D/DATA: load initial 0 30 30

after invalidate(). Why load start from 8 position after invalidate?

```
D/DATA: load initial 8 30 30
D/SAME: 0 equal 8 false
    29 equal 37 false
    0 equal 9 false
    1 equal 8 false
    28 equal 37 false
    29 equal 36 false
D/SAME: 0 equal 10 false
....
```

```
                RoomSourceFactory sourceFactory = new RoomSourceFactory(context);

        PagedList.Config config = new PagedList.Config.Builder()
                .setEnablePlaceholders(false)
                .setPageSize(10)
                .build();

        LiveData<PagedList<RoomItem>> pagedListLiveData = new LivePagedListBuilder<>(sourceFactory, config)
                .setFetchExecutor(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor())
                .build();

        roomListPagedAdapter = new RoomListPagedAdapter(
                new DiffUtil.ItemCallback<RoomItem>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean areItemsTheSame(@NonNull RoomItem oldRoomItem, @NonNull RoomItem newRoomItem) {
                        Log.d("SAME", oldRoomItem.name + " equal " + newRoomItem.name + " " + oldRoomItem.name.equals(newRoomItem.name));
                        return oldRoomItem.name.equals(newRoomItem.name);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean areContentsTheSame(@NonNull RoomItem oldRoomItem, @NonNull RoomItem newRoomItem) {
                        Log.d("CONTENT", oldRoomItem.name + " equal " + newRoomItem.name + " " + oldRoomItem.name.equals(newRoomItem.name));
                        return oldRoomItem.name.equals(newRoomItem.name);
                    }
                },
                onClickListener);

        pagedListLiveData.observe(this, new Observer<PagedList<RoomItem>>() {


            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable PagedList<RoomItem> roomItemPagedList) {
                roomListPagedAdapter.submitList(roomItemPagedList);
            }
        });

        RecyclerView recyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.community_recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

        recyclerView.setAdapter(roomListPagedAdapter);

public class RoomPositionalDataSource extends PositionalDataSource<RoomItem> {

private Context context;
private Database database;

public RoomPositionalDataSource(Context context) {
    database = new Database(context);

    new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            invalidate();
        }
    }, 10000);

}

@Override
public void loadInitial(@NonNull LoadInitialParams params, @NonNull LoadInitialCallback<RoomItem> callback) {

    int start = params.requestedStartPosition;
    int size = params.requestedLoadSize;
    List<RoomItem> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i=start; i < start + size; i++) {
        RoomItem roomItem = new RoomItem();
        roomItem.id = String.valueOf(i);
        roomItem.name = String.valueOf(i);
        result.add(roomItem);
    }

    callback.onResult(result, params.requestedStartPosition);

    Log.d("DATA", "load initial " + params.requestedStartPosition + " " + params.requestedLoadSize + " " + result.size());
}

@Override
public void loadRange(@NonNull LoadRangeParams params, @NonNull LoadRangeCallback<RoomItem> callback) {
    List<RoomItem> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i=params.startPosition; i < params.startPosition + params.loadSize; i++) {
        RoomItem roomItem = new RoomItem();
        roomItem.id = String.valueOf(i);
        roomItem.name = String.valueOf(i);
        result.add(roomItem);
    }

    callback.onResult(result);

    Log.d("DATA", "load range " + params.startPosition + " " + params.loadSize + " " + result.size());

}

}
```

[Image](https://media.giphy.com/media/8OM7HpRP6TpSNJHFTG/giphy.gif)

Comment: What i do wrong?

Comment: After call roomListPagedAdapter.submitList(roomItemPagedList);

D/DATA: load initial 69 150 150
adapter load pagedlist with offset 69 and show recyclerview at 69 position.

then load visible data, when recyclerview scroll to 69 position
D/DATA: load range 19 50 50

Comment: Someone have any ideas?

Comment: Here is LivePagedListBuilder
    protected PagedList<Value> compute() {
                @Nullable Key initializeKey = initialLoadKey;
                if (mList != null) {
                    //noinspection unchecked
                    initializeKey = (Key) mList.getLastKey();
                }
Why PagedList start load from last visible item in recyclerview?

Comment: Is it correct to use Paged Library for chat app? When items in RecyclerView changing and addind so much times. Or use endless recyclerview with onScroll stuff?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone coming to this question from search — there is a bug in paging library, more info can be found at Google issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/123834703

Comment: Please add your hint as __comment__ to the question. This is actually no answer or solution to the problem! So I recommend deleting this (false) answer.

Comment: There is solution to this question at that link. It helped me, thanks!

Comment: I'm seeing the described bug but for a PageKeyedDataSource. Is there a fix for this?